# How to find all columns where full text search index can be created?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, full-text-search

For my table `data`, I can create full text indices as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD FULLTEXT(description1, description2);
```

where `description1` and `description2` are column names.

Using JDBC, how can I find out the list of columns on which this full text search index can be created so as to avoid this error:

```
Column 'id' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea for syntax of using below query with jdbc but from information schema you can get tables and columns of specific types like below i have queried **text, varchar** you can add further types used to store text

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name, column_name, column_type
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'your database name' 
    AND column_type IN( 'text', 'varchar');
```